# How to specify StorageClass name when creating namespaced PVC with python kubernetes client

Tags: python, kubernetes

new to using the kubernetes python API client. I am trying to understand how to create a namespaced persistent volume claim using the API.  Reading the documentation I see https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CoreV1Api.md#create_namespaced_persistent_volume_claim

But I am confused as to how to specify the StorageClass I want the PVC to use. The only parameter I can see available is the namespace within which to create the PVC.